# how to get Network Status,Operator Name, Signal strength,Service status using j2me?

Tags: mobile, java-me, nokia, nokia-s40

i need to get the info of
Network Status,Operator Name, Signal strength,Service status
using the j2me API
and need to knew if i can test it over simulator or not 
thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on Series 40 devices by querying some Nokia-specific System Properties. [This page](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/#!developers-guides/system-properties/nokia-specific-system-properties.html) lists all of them. The ones you are interested are *com.nokia.mid.networksignal*, *com.nokia.mid.networkavailability* and *com.nokia.mid.networkstatus*. For the operator name, *com.nokia.mid.networkid* contains the short operator name.

To query a property, use

```
try {
    String val = System.getProperty("property name");
    // do stuff
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // property not found
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // property not found
}
```